# Undefined Variable query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Im new to code igniter

I get this error when try to create a leader board

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: query
>
> Filename: models/status_model.php
>
> Line Number: 19

And My Code look like this

```
<?php
class status_model extends CI_Model
{
function get_leaderboard(){
    //prepare a leaderboard
    $data = array();

    $details = array(
        'rank' => NULL,
        'fb_name' => NULL,
        'level' => NULL,
        'college' => NULL
    );

    $rank = 1;
    
    $sql = "SELECT fb_name, level, college, role FROM users ORDER BY level DESC, passtime ASC"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,$start*50);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            //Only regular users are shown in the leaderboard
            //banned users and admins have a rank 0, and are excluded.
            if($row->role == 1){

                $details['rank'] = $rank;
                $details['fb_name'] = $row->fb_name;
                $details['level'] = $row->level;
                $details['college'] = $row->college;
                array_push($data, $details);

                $rank++;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        //couldn't find any rows!?
        return false;
    }
    
}

function get_rank($fb_uid=''){
    //calculate rank of the current user, or given fb_uid

    if($fb_uid == ''){
        $fb_uid = $this->session->userdata('facebook_uid');
    }

    if($fb_uid=='' || $fb_uid==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    //make sure the uid corresponds to a regular user
    $sql = "SELECT fb_uid, role FROM users WHERE fb_uid = $fb_uid"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $role = $row->role;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

    if($role!=1){
        //Rank is 0 for anyone other than a regular user.
        return 0;
    }

    //count from 0 to the current user's position
    $rank = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT fb_uid FROM users WHERE role=1 ORDER BY level DESC, passtime ASC"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $rank++;
            if($row->fb_uid == $fb_uid){
                return $rank;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

function get_winners(){
    //For future use, if winner's details are 
    //added to database

    //return an empty array for now.
    $data = array();
    return $data;
}
}
```

And My HTML looks like this

```
    <?php
    $list='';

    foreach($leaderboard as $row){
            $list.="<tr>";
            $list.="<td>".$row['rank']."</td>";
            $list.="<td>".$row['fb_name']."</td>";
            $list.="<td>".$row['level']."</td>";
            $list.="<td>".$row['college']."</td>";
            $list.="</tr>";
        }

    }

    ?>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rank #</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>College</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?=$list?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you just show your problem line ? why the whole code?

Comment: what is Line Number: 19 ??

Comment: The variable `$start` is undefined.

@echo_Me it is often easier to trace the error, as in this case if you paste a bit more, just that line were he gets the error actually has no error.

Comment: @echo_Me I get #start undefined

Comment: @Emz How should i do that ? or what should i do now im pretty new

Comment: @user3237423 I added a reply now were I made some more comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a some questions regarding your question. You use an if inside your foreach instead of a `WHERE` clause in your query. Any reason you aren't using CodeIgniters built in db class? Instead of a query like `$sql = "SELECT fb_name, level, college, role FROM users WHERE rank=$rank ORDER BY level DESC, passtime ASC";` you can use `$this->db->select('fb_name'...)->where()->order_by()->get();`

Some users prefer to not chain them, instead doing $this->db in different steps.

I recommend browsing [Correct naming structure for CodeIgnitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeignitor) this url to see how naming should be done in CodeIgniter

Also, this should work, making it both more effiecient and cleaner, it only gets queries where the rank is 1. Then gets the results from them, if there are more than 0 results then generating the results.

```
<?php if (!defined(‘BASEPATH’)) exit(‘No direct script access allowed’); 
class status_model extends CI_Model {

    function get_leaderboard(){

        $sql = "SELECT fb_name, level, college, role FROM users WHERE rank=1 ORDER BY level DESC, passtime ASC"; 

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            $data = $query->result();
            return $data;
        } else {

            //couldn't find any rows!?
            return false;
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use it like that

```
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```