# Displaying data from database using codeigniter php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i want to display my data form db using php code ignitor. this is what i have done up till now but cant get results.

> Its  message of undefined variable query

. please have a look and suggest the what should i do or any alternate way to display data from database tables. 
View:

```
<tbody>
                                        <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
                                        <tr>   
                                        <td><?php echo $row->subuid; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row->uid; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Model:

```
public function showusers(){
    function viewusers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('sub_users')->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

COntroller:

```
function showusers()
{    
$this->load->model('User_area_model');
$data4['query'] = $this->session->viewusers();   
$this->load->view('manage-users', $data4);
}
```

Comment: Problem in your model and controller. please refer doc first.

Comment: What does "cant get results" mean? What have you tried to debug this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined Variable query in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363181/undefined-variable-query-in-codeigniter)

Comment: kindly mentioned the problem with the. i have already mentioned i want to display database data into my web page. i already know there is something wrong in model and controller. i am new to codeignitor.

Comment: `print_r($query->result());` before returning the value from model and make sure the query returns some value.

Comment: you are fetching data from session, not from the model.try $data4['query'] = $this->User_area_model->viewusers();

Answer (score 1):

Your `controller` should be like this :

```
function showusers()
{    
  $this->load->model('User_area_model');

  /*replace this $this->session->viewusers() with User_area_model;*/ 

  $data4['query'] = $this->User_area_model->viewusers(); 
  if ( !empty($data4['query']))
  {

      $this->load->view('manage-users', $data4);
  }
  else
  {
     echo 'no record found';
  }
}
```

Model :

```
   public function viewusers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('sub_users');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

View : check for `empty` in view

```
<tbody>
<?php if (! empty($query) ) { 
      foreach($query as $row): ?>
        <tr>   
         <td><?php echo $row->subuid; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->uid; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php  endforeach;
 }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: undefined variable $query shows because it is empty pls put check for empty in the view before the foreach loop , or in controller as in my answer

Answer (score 1):

try this,

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
<?php if($query){ ?>
    <?php foreach($query as $row){ ?>
    <tr>   
        <td><?= $row->subuid; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->uid; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->fname; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row->lname; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

**MODEL**

```
public function viewusers(){
    $this->db->select('*')->from('sub_users');       
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function showusers(){    
    $this->load->model('User_area_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->User_area_model->viewusers();   
    $this->load->view('manage-users', $data);
}
```