# Transferring codeigniter HMVC project from localhost to live server

Tags: codeigniter, web-hosting, hmvc

I made a web application on codeigniter HMVC. I tested it on local server and the following link works perfectly fine by giving me a login form, the link : http://localhost/bird_vision/users/login, where my directory structure goes like this bird_vision/application/modules/users/users.php (users->module's name, users.php->controller's name). Now I posted the whole "bird_vision" folder to web using filezilla. 
- changed the base_url in config.php file to domain_name
- Made some changes in .htaccess file

```
    # Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$10 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Now when I write bird_vision.se/bird_vision/users/login in my address bar it gives me 404 page not found. Although when I when type birdvision.se/bird_vision/welcome it gives me welcome to codeigniter page.

Please I need help as my all hardwork making this project is at stake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: give it a try with bird_vision.se/bird_vision/users/users/login.

Comment: If you migrate from windows test lower and upper case in accordance with Codeigniter's  requirements

Comment: @splash can you please give me a link to find the lower and uppercase requirement of codeigniter with for unix/linux server. I googled a lot caould'nt find anything. Thanks. And yes I am migrating the project from windows to unix/linix based server.

Comment: Look there  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeignitor

Comment: I did, no help. I figured out the problem is because of the case sensitive difference between the two operating systems. Giving the call to default controller gets me to the page "Welcome to code igniter" but as soon as the HMVC comes into play it is just not able to load the module and gets me a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem was not with HMVC but was with codeigniter version 3.0. When it comes to unix(which was the operating system running on my server), it is case sensitive. So when I tried to access the controller it could'nt find the file because of case sensitivity and a 404 popped out everytime.

My folder structure before was something like :

```
-application
-->modules
--->users
---->controllers
----->users.php
```

And the link on which I was getting 404 was www.example.com/users/login

where "users" in the link is controller's name within the "controllers" folder under "modules" folder in my case named as users.php and "login" is the function inside the controller.

All I had to do was to change the case of the first letter of my module and controller name. Now my directory looks like

```
-application
-->modules
--->Users
---->controllers
----->Users.php
```

note : capitalized "U" in Users module and Users controller.

And the the url I used to access the users controller was : www.example.com/**U**sers/login

And I was back in business.