# Code-igniter controllers file name can not start with capital letter

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, routes, frameworks

I was using small letter for controller file name before,

however, recently move the file to other server that need to controller name to be start with capital

=========================================

Here is the rename example :

**file name:** Home.php

**$route['default_controller']:** "home";

**link:** http://example.com/index_folder/

==========================================

it show error of

```
Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.
```

And when I change the route to

**$route['default_controller']:** "Home";

it still show the same error,

Only success if I go to

```
http://example.com/index_folder/Home/
```

How to fix that? Thanks for helping

**Update**

Here is the htaccess file, at the root of the project folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

The reason of rename is it seems the new server has problem if my Controller is in lower case

Comment: What you try to achieve here? Using lowercase inside config file is fine. Do you have htaccess with mod rewrite there ?

Comment: this syntax will also work http://example.com/index_folder/home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct naming structure for CodeIgnitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeignitor)

Comment: Suspicious inside Home.php dosent have index function ?

Comment: yes have index function

Comment: maybe quite difficult to fix first , any way to debug / test to know which part is the root of the problem?

Comment: Read my comment on answer below

Comment: Try rmove <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> part and just leave rewrite mode without it

Comment: The link `http://example.com/index_folder/` implies that `Home.php` is on a path like this `/application/controllers/index_folder/Home.php` Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive, keep the file name and class name same and try again. It will work.

The same code will work fine on  windows but give exception on Linux.

Comment: before is file name is in smaller letter and class name in controller is capital letter,  it does not match but work so far before, very strange

Comment: @user782104 Try using Capital for file name in case Home.php is correct and Using capital too for class name, example Homecontroller. I once upload CI to namespace and they server didnt recognize camelcase class name "HomeController".

Answer (score 0):

As per [Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html),

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                echo 'Hello World!';
        }
}
```

Then save the file to your **application/controllers/** directory.

**Important:-**

> The file must be called ‘Home.php’, with a capital ‘H’.

Now visit the your site using a URL similar to this:

**example.com/index.php/home/**

CodeIgniter can be told to load a default controller when a URI is not present, as will be the case when only your site root URL is requested.

To specify a default controller, open your `application/config/routes.php` file and set this variable:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Where ‘home’ is the name of the controller class you want used.

If you now load your main index.php file without specifying any URI segments you’ll see your “Hello World” message by default.