# Why is my particular controller not working in CodeIgniter 3.0?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm new with Codeigniter and this is the first time I encounter this issue. I have a project that has many models, controllers, and multilevel views. All, but one of my controller is not working. I'll try my best to explain my issue.

Let's say I have controller A and Controller B.

**Link from view to access each controller:**

```
//This link go to Con A
<a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>ConA/user">TEST1</a>

//This link go to Con B
<a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>ConB/user2">TEST2</a>
```

**Con A**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ConA extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('MAdmin');
}

public function user()
{
   $data = array (
        'titlepage' => APP_TITLEPAGE,
        'titleapp' => 'User Management',            
        'listdept' => $this->MAdmin->get_dept(),
        'complete' => 'false',
        'contentpage' => 'admin/user');//This is the view directory. Will open user.php in myproject/application/views/admin

    $this->load->view('shared/master_app', $data);
}
```

**Con B**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ConB extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('MAdmin');
}

public function user2()
{
   $data = array (
        'titlepage' => APP_TITLEPAGE,
        'titleapp' => 'User Management',            
        'listdept' => $this->MAdmin->get_dept(),
        'complete' => 'false',
        'contentpage' => 'admin/user');//This is the view directory. Will open user.php in myproject/application/views/admin

    $this->load->view('shared/master_app', $data);
}
```

**shared/master_app in Views**

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content"><?php $this->load->view($contentpage); ?></div>
```

**$config**

```
$config['base_url']= "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

**.htaccess in myproject/**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess in myproject/application**

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>Require all denied</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>Deny from all</IfModule>
```

**Note:**

- In offline mode (Localhost) everything is run well
- the URL in the address bar after a redirect from the link is the same (except the naming).

Comment: You Should Check this. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Comment: Not an expert but I am facing problem in the beginning when I start Codeigniter, in local my all URL is running ok but on the server that create problems and didn't load. So I found that I didn't follow the naming convention of CI. So You should check that first.

Comment: Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16972966/5077564

Comment: what is the URL? Please add the access URL in your question.

Comment: It seem  my new controller is not registered. I solve my problem by merge the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost working well, The main cause of an issue is controller name which is  `ConA` or `ConB` . Classes name start from Capital keyword. Please rename the Controller class and save the file as `Cona.php` . Maybe it works. Sometimes this issue creates a lot of bugs. First, try with this. Also Your URLs should be all lowercase letters. You can write anchor tag like as , e.g. :

```
<a href="<?php print base_url('conb/user2'); ?>">TEST2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please enable mod_rewrite in php.ini file of your live server