# Error after uploading codeigniter website to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload codeigniter website from local to server but i am getting error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Membership
>
> Filename:
>   /home/creatfam/public_html/allshoppo.in/medical/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/creatfam/public_html/allshoppo.in/medical/application/controllers/Manage_admin.php
>   Line: 65 Function: model
>
> File: /home/creatfam/public_html/allshoppo.in/medical/index.php Line:
>   315 Function: require_once

Comment: this is perfect working on my local server

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Model Names  are case sensitive.
- Make sure your model name and file names are the same.
- It will run on localhost since if you are using windows environment the URLs are - case insensitive.
  Better have a look at the accepted answer here.
  [Correct naming structure for CodeIgnitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeignitor)

Answer (score 1):

**Refer this** =>
Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

For more idea : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Answer (score 1):

Please follow codeigniter rules for creating and calling models in controllers

1. Make the model class name Uppercase My_model
2. Make the model PHP file name Lowercase my_model
3. Load the model using Lowercase (file name) $this->load->model('my_model');

See eaxmple here :

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    ...

}
```

**In controller file :**

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->model('test_model');
    ...

}
```