# Unable to load the requested class: Phpmailer_library

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to use phpmailer library, I downloaded codeigniter 3 fresh version and used composer by following steps

```
1 . $config['composer_autoload'] = true;
```

Then I put composer.json file into application folder.

2. **composer install** into application location
3. vendor folder has been created.
4. I created a new file PHPMailer.php location
   `/opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/testone/application/vendor` with code

   class PHPMailer_Library
   {
       public function __construct()
       {
           log_message('Debug', 'PHPMailer class is loaded.');
       }

   ```
   public function load()
   {
       $objMail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
       return $objMail;
   }
   ```

   }

then I am created new controller Testing

```
class Testing extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library("phpmailer_library");
        $objMail = $this->phpmailer_library->load();
    }
}
```

Now I am getting error like:

```
Unable to load the requested class: Phpmailer_library.
```

Please give me suggestion what I am missing.

Comment: You are getting error because of naming, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeigniter) link and libraries naming convention

Comment: @JigarShah Actually I am not getting where I am not taking wrong naming convention.

Comment: class name `PHPMailer_Library`

Comment: @JigarShah so according to you what should be right name

Comment: have a look on [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for creating libraries, also check name of file which needs to be same as your class name