# HMVC codeigniter MX URI routing broken, application\third_party\MX\Router.php

Tags: codeigniter

```
 I using HMVC of Codeigniter first time.
```

From application\third_party\MX\Router.php file view this error!

```
A PHP Error was encountered
        Severity: Notice
        
        Message: Undefined offset: 0
        
        Filename: core/Router.php
        
        Line Number: 268
        
        Backtrace:
        
        File: F:\server\htdocs\HMVC_Task\application\third_party\MX\Router.php
        Line: 190
        Function: _set_request
        
        File: F:\server\htdocs\HMVC_Task\index.php
        Line: 315
        Function: require_once
        
        404 Page Not Found
        The page you requested was not found.
```

Codeigniter version is 3.1.11.

Now I'm trying to fix it by googling.

If any one have any suggestion please share.

Comment: might be a naming convention problem, how are you calling the Class? what's the filename? maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970803/correct-naming-structure-for-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks but that was version related error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 That was version related error.

 **Now I understand the solution.**

**When you use: codeigniter V2:**
    In CI v2.x finished with $this->_set_request($this->uri->segments);



**When you use: codeigniter V3:**
    whereas CI v3.0-dev finishes with $this->_set_request(array_values($this->uri->segments));
```